# How to get an Angular directive to render when added to the dom outside of Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to get an Angular directive to render when added to the dom outside of Angular?

I’m in the process of slowly introducing angular to an existing codebase.  There exists a table with a bunch of rows in the dom.  Each row contains a spinner element, which is controlled by a directive:

```
<tr>
  <td>stuff</td>
  <td><div spinner></div></td>
<tr>

joyableApp.directive('spinner', [function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'spinner.html',
  }
}]);
```

Now- when the `<div spinner>` is in the dom on page load, the spinner directive is correctly activated and the `spinner.html` template is properly rendered inside that div.

However, there’s a button on this page that will add additional rows to the table.  The query governing that button is:

```
$(“#new-row-button”).click(function(e) {
  $.get(“/get_new_row_content”, function(data) {
    $(“#table tbody”).append(data);
  });
});
```

The html returned from `/get_new_row_content` is pretty much just the html shown above, and contains `<div spinner>`.  Dom inspection verifies that the spinner element is added to the page.  However, the `spinner.html` template is not getting rendered.  The spinner directive isn’t getting triggered when this new row is added.

Note that this jquery code is not in any controller, service, factory, or any other angular thing.

So, how do I get the angular directive to pick up the new row?

I suspect that the *correct* answer is to make the whole page be controlled by angular, including the ‘add row’ button, but I don’t have the time to do that.  I need a short-term bridge between angular and the existing code.

**TLDR:**  How do I get an angular directive to trigger for a dom element that was dynamically to the page from outside of angular?

Comment: You should use $compile('your html')(scope) and append this to your table. I think

Comment: How do I get access to `$compile` outside of angular (ie, in that jquery ajax callback)?

Comment: var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']); and then $injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
   //compile and inject here
});

Comment: Thanks- that did the trick!  Had to actually do injector['ng','myAppModule'] to get the directive I was trying to trigger to trigger.  I'll write up a slightly better-formatted answer to leave here for posterity, unless you want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the $compile service and then inject the result into your page:

```
$(“#new-row-button”).click(function(e) {
  $.get(“/get_new_row_content”, function(data) {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng','any other needed modules']);
    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope,$compile){
        $(“#table tbody”).append($compile(data)($rootScope));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Always building against $rootScope may not give the expected results, the scope of the element being used to add the element should be used.

Comment: Don't create ANOTHER instance of the injector. It was already created for you when the app was loaded by angular, use that one. See my post on how to access it from an angular element. You then also do not need to worry about dependent modules as it includes all of the modules pulled in from ng-app.

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing to do would be to have the  have an ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="rowData in allRowData">
```

The button could then have an an ng-click that adds new data to the allRowData array. and update the  to display the data you want to see in rowData.

The above would be the correct way to implement angular for your use. Ignoring that advice do build and add content on the fly you can do the following outside angular.

```
var elem = angular.element(jQuery(“#table tbody”));
elem.injector().invoke(function($compile){
    elem.append($compile(html)(elem.scope()));
})
```